# How to connect AnyView with String name?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

[image: IMAGE HERE]

I want to make my first app - it will be my resume(cv). Here is what I created in my mind:

- I want to have multiple buttons connected with many views. all displayed in grid with 2 columns
- inside of each view Ii will have different things, like education info, gallery, and later - my portfolio apps.

I want to join somehow views with titles - how can I do it better without json?

I did it like this: views and titles are done separately. Is there any better way to do this without json?

One important thing: I want to have more than 10 buttons, so I want to do it with arrays instead of placing just buttons separately.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    let columns = [
        GridItem(.flexible()),
        GridItem(.flexible())
    ]
    
    let buttonsViews: [AnyView] = [
        AnyView(AboutView()),
        AnyView(EducationView()),
        AnyView(GalleryView())
    ]
    
    let titles: [String] = [
    "About",
    "Education",
    "Gallery"
    ]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack{
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
                ForEach(buttonsViews.indices, id: \.self) { ind in
                    NavigationLink("\(titles[ind])") {
                        buttonsViews[ind]
                    }
                    .frame(height: 50)
                    .frame(minWidth: 100)
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.black)
                    .cornerRadius(5)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to improve and be more specific in what you’re asking because “how to do it better” is too vague.

Comment: you are right: i want to have something like dictionary :
var buttons = [

„About” :  AnyView(AboutView()),
„Education” :  AnyView(EducationView()),
„Gallery” :  AnyView(GalleryView()),

 ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `AnyView`, you're probably doing it wrong. Try an array of enums representing each view (`about`, `education`, `gallery`, etc), then `ForEach` on the array, switch on their enum, and return the relevant View.

```
enum ButtonType: Identifiable, CaseIterable {
    var id: Self { self }
    case about, education, gallery
    
    var title: String {
        switch self {
        case .about: return "About"
        case .education: return "Education"
        case .gallery: return "Gallery"
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    let columns = [
        GridItem(.flexible()),
        GridItem(.flexible())
    ]
    

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack{
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
                ForEach(ButtonType.allCases) { type in
                    NavigationLink(type.title) {
                        switch type {
                        case .about:
                            Text("AboutView")
                        case .education:
                            Text("EducationView")
                        case .gallery:
                            Text("GalleryViewView")
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(height: 50)
                    .frame(minWidth: 100)
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.black)
                    .cornerRadius(5)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, it is what i was thinking about, but when i tried to do this i forget about putting id variable, so it was not working for me.

Comment: It's all part of the learning process!